# angular.js: Dynamic navigation depending on login status

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following routing with athentication, which is done via a PHP-Script and MySQL:

**app.config**

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/login', {
            title: 'Login',
            templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
            controller: 'authCtrl'
        })
        .when('/logout', {
            title: 'Logout',
            templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
            controller: 'logoutCtrl'
        })

        .when('/dashboard', {
            title: 'Dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'authCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/login'
        });
  }])
    .run(function ($rootScope, $location, Data) {
        $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            Data.get('session').then(function (results) {
                if (results.uid) {
                    $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                    $rootScope.uid = results.uid;
                    $rootScope.name = results.name;
                    $rootScope.email = results.email;
                } else {
                    var nextUrl = next.$$route.originalPath;
                    if (nextUrl == '/signup' || nextUrl == '/login') {

                    } else {
                        $location.path("/login");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

**authCtrl**

```
app.controller('authCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, $location, $http, Data) {
    $scope.login = {};
    $scope.signup = {};
    $scope.doLogin = function (customer) {
        Data.post('login', {
            customer: customer
        }).then(function (results) {
            Data.toast(results);
            if (results.status == "success") {
                $location.path('dashboard');
            }
        });
    };
    $scope.logout = function () {
        Data.get('logout').then(function (results) {
            Data.toast(results);
            $location.path('login');
        });
    }
});
```

Now I want to change the navigation depending on the login-status. If user is logged in there should bei a logOUT-Button and a link to the dashboard. If the user isn't logged in it should look like this

**sample for unlogged-in user**

```
 <header id="navigation">
     <nav id="main">
         <ul>
             <li id="login"><a href="#/login" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Login</a></li>
         </ul>
     </nav>
 </header>
 <main ng-view>
    Content goes here
 </main>
```

What is the best way for creating the navigation? Should it be a seperate template?

Answer (score 0):

When things get complex, I'd rather use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) or maybe angular new router (haven't try this one yet) since they support multiple views in the same page. Thus nav becomes its own view, content its own view, etc.  And to communicate between the views I'll use message passing with data in either `$rootScope` or some kind of shared state service.

So something like this... in the beginning, the login shared state is set to **logged out**.  As the last part of login functionality, I'd set the login shared state and set it to **logged in**.  Like I said, I rather make this a shared state service call since I can have it to also do `$rootScope.$broadcast` some sort of **onLoginStateChange** and pass the new value there.

Then I'd set up my nav view to listen to this **onLoginStateChange** using `$scope.$on` and set its internal view model state in its controller and bind that to `ng-if` directive so it will display **Login** if **false**, or **Logout** if **true** (logged in).

Comment: Can you please write a code example when using ui-router? I think I have to use ui-router...